# Python SQLite3 - Table Output Format Question & Handling IntegrityError

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table created using Python + Sqlite3

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reg(col1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY, col2 TEXT)')
```

I even wrote a record into it using val1 and val2 variables which have string values (URLs to be specific)

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO reg VALUES(?,?)', (val1, val2))
```

Now when I print the table using this code

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM reg')
rows = c.fetchall()
print rows
```

It shows output as

```
[(u'http://www.someURL.com', u'http://www.someURL.com/someDIR/')]
```

Now, what is this **u** in front of my column values mean?

**EDIT:** My next doubt is in continuation to this question so I am updating this thread instead of creating a new one. I have updated the title too. Hope that's OK.

From the above code, It is clear that my col1 is a Primary Key. So, when I tried to purposefully insert the same records for the second time it throws the exception

```
IntegrityError: column col1 is not unique
```

In order to handle this, I modified the code like this...

```
try:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO reg VALUES(?,?)', (val1, val2))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print val1+ " is already in the database"
```

Now executing this code caused me this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\dbUrl.py", line 47, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO reg VALUES(?,?)', (val1,val2))
OperationalError: database is locked
```

Any idea how do I resolve this? Infact, I don't even understand what this OperationError mean and what made the DB to be locked?

Comment: Might want to update the variable names in the code snippet so it's clear that's actually the same line as the line in the error?

Comment: Yes, I updated the variable names. Sorry, should have done it before. Val1 is the same value I am trying to insert twice into col1. Col1 is a primary key.

Comment: GOD knows what happened Lol Now, I executed my program again and after giving it some 5 minutes rest and now its fine. But I really wonder what caused the DB lock although it works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `u` means those are Unicode strings. They can be encoded to any character set you want:

```
u'http://www.someURL.com'.encode('ascii') # or 'latin-1' or 'utf-8'
```

You'll get back the same string without the `u` because they're all ASCII characters.

See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html.

If the strings only contain ASCII characters (all the normal symbols on an English keyboard) then you don't have to worry too much about this. If, however, you're using an extended character set, you need to make sure you're specifying the right encoding when saving strings or displaying them to the user.

Edit: When I execute

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.isolation_level = None
c = con.cursor()

val1, val2 = 'a', 'b'

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reg(col1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY, col2 TEXT)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO reg VALUES(?,?)', (val1, val2))
try:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO reg VALUES(?,?)', (val1, val2))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print val1, "is already in the database"
```

I get `a is already in the database`. (Note the proper way to do that print statement, although yours is perfectly valid.) So your problem is somewhere else -- `locked` means something else is writing to the database. Try this with an in memory database as I did, so you know for sure nothing else is accessing it. If this works, your problem is what the exception indicates -- something else is accessing the database.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Also you have mentioned `Note the proper way to do that print statement, although yours is perfectly valid.` So I am just wondering what is the best way? Did you mean using + in print statement is not the correct way? Instead use **,** ? I would like to hear what you have to say. Thanks!

Comment: When you use `+` with strings, you're creating a new string. This involves making copies of the old strings. When you're using `print`, there is no reason to do that. `print` will automatically format things as strings and will insert a space wherever there is a comma (and a newline at the end of the line unless you end the line with a comma). If `val1` was an int, `print val1, string` would work, while `print val1 + string` wouldn't, you'd have to `print str(val1) + string`.

Answer (score 1):

That means the strings are encoded as [Unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).

Comment: Oh okay, now I get it! I tried viewing it in the SQLite Manager firefox add on and the rows are just fine... I mean they are displayed without the **u**. I guess in command prompt it shows with what format it is encoded too. Good! Now I get it.